# Prevent context menu from opening on a right click over element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my website to have a custom interaction when the user right clicks on an element, `<div class="myElement"></div>`. Thus, I don't what the context menu to also pop up when the element is right clicked as to not spoil the UX. Is there a way to do this (preferably in CSS, but vanilla js works too)?

Desired:

```
.myElement {
    contextMenuOnRightClick: none,
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The easiest way is with some very simple JavaScript:

```
<div class="myElement" oncontextmenu="return false;"></div>
```

- `oncontextmenu`: event fires when the context menu (right-click menu) is shown.
- `return false;`: cancels the event; which stops the menu from showing.

Yet better, instead of using **inline JS**, create a reusable className `.js-noMenu` and add it to any element that should prevent right clicks.
Place the JS lines into your Javascript file.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll(".js-noMenu")].forEach( el => 
 el.addEventListener('contextmenu', e => e.preventDefault())
);
```

```html
<div class="js-noMenu">Right click me!</div>
<p>You <b>can</b> contextmenu me!</p>
<p class="js-noMenu">You cannot here</p>
```

basically *[`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)* prevents the browser from triggering default actions

Comment: Try to avoid inline JS

Comment: Why do we need to avoid inline js, though, other than its ugly?

Comment: Well, if your project consists of no-JS-file / scripts - than it's arguably *OK*. But as soon your project grows, having disseminated inline scripts makes your project really hardly maintainable.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I tend to agree. I suggested an inline solution as it will probably be easier for OP to understand if they haven't use JS much before, and their preference for CSS implied there was probably not much other JS in the project (at least the part OP is working on)

Comment: @Toastrackenigma if you don't mind, I merged the two answers

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Awesome, I was going to suggest a similar edit :)

Answer (score 1):

A few thing needs to be pointed out:

- Event.preventDefault() works, but may produced error/restriction sounds on some browsers (e.g. Chrome) and since you plan to implement a custom action, this may not be the best solution for you.
- You will write a lot of pure vanilla JS to make it work across all browsers as implementing cross browser selector alone will require a lot of code without a library like jQuery.
- Adding over 50k of jQuery library for something like this is absurd (Unless of course you need the library for other things).
- You can still inline it using a value that means the same thing as the JS equivalent and make your code look still beautiful.
- It's a lot of work to support items dynamically added to the page with JS.

Use something like this:

```
<div class="myElement" oncontextmenu="return!1"></div>
```

Comment: Good points, but *"SpecificEvent"*.preventDefault() is not exactly like `Event.stopPropagation()` - which could indeed cause event-bubbling trouble.

Comment: Why the cryptic `return!1` ? If evaulates to `false` anyways. let's make code for people. Also `return false` is discouraged in favor of `preventDefault` (without stopping propagation)

Comment: :) it is but... yeah

Answer (score 1):

This is my favorite and simplest approach (one of my first lines of my custom JS)...

```
/* disable right click */
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
```